# How JVM control the off-heap memory if I enable the off-heap storage

Tags: apache-spark

I am using Spark 3.0 and run application on yarn. I have set the following two options :

```
spark.memory.offHeap.enabled=true
spark.memory.offHeap.size=2G
```

My question is: with these two configurations, when spark submits the application on yarn, spark need to tell YARN that the yarn container process should occupy/use 2G off-heap memory.(forget overhead memory here.)

I think Spark should provide some JVM options in the Driver/Executor Process launch script to YARN, such as `-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize` or `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize`
so that when YARN kicks off the JVM container process, the container can be started with some JVM options,

I don't know if I understand correctly,but when I look through Spark's source code, I didn't find the JVM options `-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize` or `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize`

Comment: Can some guy answer this question? Thanks